Expectation of log-normal random variables
I’m working through a derivation to understand how noise in the concentration threshold $C_\theta$ affects the width  of the transition zone in the French Flag model. The model assumes that concentration thresholds $C_\theta$ determine boundaries between different cell fates, and in a noise-free environment, the boundary position is given by:
\begin{equation*}
    x = \lambda \ln\left(\frac{C_0}{C_\theta}\right).
\end{equation*}
where:
λ is a decay length with units of length (e.g., micrometres),
$C_\theta$ and $C_0$ are concentrations, which have units of molarity (e.g., M or mol/L).
To continue we now imagine that cells can't interpret the readout concentration perfectly and thus the quantity $C_{\theta,1}$ has some uncertainty associated with it. This uncertainty is modelled by drawing $C_\theta$ from a log-normal distribution $C_\theta \sim LN\left(\mu_{C_\theta}, \sigma^2\right)$. Thus if we want to define a readout position $x_1$, we now have to consider an expected readout position $\mathbb{E}[x]$. Therefore, in expectation a boundary forms at the following position,
\begin{gather*}
    C_{\theta,1} \sim LN\left(\mu_{C_\theta}, \sigma_{C_\theta}^2\right) \\
    \mathbb{E}[x_1] = \lambda \mathbb{E}\left[\ln(\frac{C_0}{C_{\theta,1}})\right]. 
\end{gather*}
Similarly we can ask ourselves where in expectation a second boundary would be placed,
\begin{gather*}
    C_{\theta,2} \sim L N\left(\mu_{C_\theta}, \sigma_{C_\theta}^2\right) \\
    \mathbb{E}[x_2] = \lambda \mathbb{E}\left[\ln(\frac{C_0}{C_{\theta,2}})\right]. 
\end{gather*}
From these two boundaries we can define an expected width,
\begin{gather*}
    \mathbb{E}[w] = \mathbb{E}\left[|x_2 - x_1|\right] = \lambda \mathbb{E}\left[ |\ln(\frac{C_0}{C_{\theta,2}})  - \ln(\frac{C_0}{C_{\theta,1}})|\right] = \lambda  \mathbb{E}\left[|\ln(\frac{C_{\theta,1}}{C_{\theta,2}})|\right].
\end{gather*}
Using the fact that taking the log of a log-normally variable distributed leads to a normally distributed variable, we can transform the equation above into the difference of to normally distributed variables, called $Z$, which is also normally distributed, with the following mean and variance,
\begin{gather*}
    \mu_Z = \mu_{C_\theta} - \mu_{C_\theta} = 0 \\
    \sigma^2_Z = \sigma_{C_\theta}^2 + \sigma_{C_\theta}^2 = 2\sigma_{C_\theta}^2.
\end{gather*}
Calculating the expected value of of $|Z|$ leads to,
\begin{gather*}
    \mathbb{E}[|Z|] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|C_\theta|z_{C_\theta}(C_\theta) dC_\theta = \frac{1}{\sigma_Z \sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|C_\theta| \exp(-\frac{1}{2}(C_\theta/\sigma_z)^2) dC_\theta = \\  
    \frac{1}{\sigma_Z \sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{0}-C_\theta \exp(-\frac{1}{2}(C_\theta/\sigma_z)^2) dC_\theta + \int_{0}^{\infty} C_\theta \exp(-\frac{1}{2}(C_\theta/\sigma_z)^2) dC_\theta 
    \right] = \\ \frac{1}{\sigma_Z \sqrt{2\pi}} \left( \sigma_Z^2 + \sigma_z^2 \right) = 
    \frac{2\sigma_Z^2}{\sigma_Z \sqrt{2\pi}} =  \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma_Z = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sigma_{C_\theta}.
\end{gather*}
Leading to an expected value for the width of the transition zone,
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb{E}[w] = \frac{2\lambda\sigma_{C_\theta}}{\sqrt{\pi}}.
\end{equation*}
Here’s my issue:
The transition zone width  should have units of length (e.g., micrometeres). However,
$\sigma_{C_\theta}$ is the standard deviation of concentration and therefore has units of concentration (e.g., mol/L). Since  has units of length and $\sigma_{C_\theta}$ has units of concentration, the result appears to combine incompatible units of length and concentration, which should not be the case for a width measurement.
Is there an error in my derivation, or am I misinterpreting something about the units in this context?

I do not understand where the problem is. By  $x = \lambda \ln(\frac{C_0}{C_\theta})$ the quantity $x$ has the same unit (aka "dimension") as $\lambda$ and the argument of $\ln$ is dimensionless whatever the unit of $C,.$ This does not change when you model $C$ as a stochastic variable. I believe your mistake is in thinking that when $C$ is lognormal that its $\sigma_C$ has a unit. This is wrong. When $C$ is lognormal it is $C_\theta=C_0\exp(\sigma_C,\varepsilon-\sigma_c^2/2)$ with $\varepsilon\sim N(0,1)$ and where only $C_0$ has a unit ...

... and all the rest (including $\sigma_c$ ) is dimensionless. This is because the exponential term models a percentage (relative) change and not an absolute one.

Thank you very much for the answer!
